# how to bind variable in factory to view

Tags: angularjs

I have searched through the net for my query. I found some answer but not what i was looking for. So i am posting here.

I have a factory which has an object named risk.

```
angularApp.factory('RiskMinderFactory', function(){

var risk = {
        a: '',
        b: '',
        c: '',

};

});
```

I have a view that is an jsp

```
<form>
    <input id="input_3"  name= "a" value={{risk.a}} />
    <input id="input_4"  name= "b" value={{risk.b}} /> 
</form>
```

In my old application i have a third party java script which takes form object as input and makes some modification to dom element.

What i want is when the 3rd party javscript makes some dom changes it should be reflected in factory object.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

First off you're going to need a scope, and a controller to inject that service into. But if you inject that service into the controller responsible for that particular view, then add the data it returns to the scope and you should be able to use those values in the view.

```
angularApp.factory('RiskMinderFactory', function(){

  var risk = {
    a: '',
    b: '',
    c: '',
  };

  return {
    getData: function () {
      return risk;
    }
  };

});
```

Then in your controller

```
angularApp.controller('SpecialController', function ($scope, RiskMinderFactory) {
  $scope.risk = RiskMinderFactory.getData();
});
```